# Anaconda Desktop Navigator Cannot Connect to Anaconda Nucleus (Cloud)

Tags: authentication, anaconda, navigator

I am using a free version of the Anaconda desktop navigator (on windows 10), and I am having difficulty connecting to my Anaconda Nucleus account (in the past, I was able to connect and successfully backup my environments). When I am using the web UI, I can use my credentials (username, email, password) to login into both "https://anaconda.cloud/" (Nucleus) and "anaconda.org" (Dashboard) without any problem. However, in the desktop navigator, I can only connect to "anaconda.org". When I use my credentials to connect to Anaconda Nucleus I get the following error (see the attached screenshot):
HTTPConnectionPool(host='anaconda.cloud',port=443):Max retries exceeded with url:/api/

I already reset my password and authenticate my credentials. I also tried to clear Anaconda cash using this command: (conda clean --all) in the Anaconda Powershell Terminal. However, I still can't connect to the Anaconda Nucleus (cloud)!

Please advise.

[Error Message Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmzRn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I received from the Anaconda tech support:

*The errors that you are receiving indicate a network connection problem. The server is not accepting the URL that you are providing with the token in it.

This could be caused by an invalid token, but more likely it is caused by an incorrect proxy setting, ssl, or firewall setting.

1. Make sure that you are using a valid token to authenticate to the anaconda.cloud professional repository.
2. https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-commercial/troubleshooting/#http-000-connection-failed
   This link tells you how to turn off ssl_verify. If that is the problem, the connection should work with ssl off. Many people do use it that way. However, if your company needs ssl_verify on, you will have to work with your IT or Network Department to resolve the issue.
3. If you need to use Anaconda behind a firewall or proxy, instructions for doing so can be found here:
   https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda-commercial/troubleshooting/#http-000-connection-failed
   Corporate security policies may prevent a new Anaconda installation from downloading packages and other functionality that requires connecting to an external server. To make external connections you may need to connect to a firewall/proxy. Additionally, your IT team may need to allow connections to https://anaconda.org and https://repo.anaconda.com and https://repo.anaconda.cloud/ as these are the main package repositories.*

Comment: Just an update on the above issue: after following up with the IT department, it turn out the problem was indeed the firewall/proxy they put in place for network security. I was able to log in and connect to the Anaconda Nucleus in the desktop navigator as soon as they turn off the firewall!